# what is the deep meaning of this quote by Grothendieck?

Tags: quotation

what is the deep meaning of this quote ?

"A good mathematician always soaks his nuts while trying to solve a problem."

by [Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck)

Reference:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5499/which-mathematicians-have-influenced-you-the-most/5828#5828

Comment: What is the source of this quote? And what makes you presume it has a "deep meaning"?

Comment: @JochenGlueck [see this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/5828/157193)

Comment: Are you sure you have a correct translation? "Soaks his nut" (singular) could mean gets drunk as "nut" is a synonym for brain in some cultures. It needn't mean gonads and it might just be a dirty joke if it does. "Grothendieck" is a bit of a synonym for "odd duck", actually.

Comment: I don't know that interpreting proverbs should be on-topic for Academia.SE, regardless of whether an academic said something.

Comment: In the context of the linked question, a "nut" is a hard problem. Soaking the nut is softening it up, much the way that Einstein worked toward relativity. "If I'm traveling at the speed of light holding a mirror, will I see my image?"

Comment: @BryanKrause, If my latest comment is correct, then it really is on-topic here.

Comment: Im not sure  sir @Buffy I just copy and paste from the given link

Comment: This has little to do with academia. Better to ask on mathematics.se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that he is just being a bit "dirty" or politically incorrect to make the point that hard problems (nuts) need to be softened up (soaked) in order to attack them.

Much of Einstein's work toward relativity was just a thought experiment based on the experimental work that preceded him. He was trying to determine whether the aether existed as a medium for the propagation of light.

His fundamental insight came from asking himself "If I'm traveling at the speed of light holding a mirror, will I see my image?". He pondered that for a long time and it helped him bridge the gap from 19th to 20th century physics.

Academics aren't always "nice" in the way they express things. It can be interpreted as "playful" or offensive.

Answer (score 14):

Grothendieck never said what you claim he said.

In fact, this question seems a bit disingenuous. You provided [this MathOverflow link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5499/which-mathematicians-have-influenced-you-the-most/5828#5828), but in fact, you have quoted only the last comment in the thread, which is pretty obviously a joke. If you look just two comments above the one you quoted, you'll see that someone already provided the actual quote you are asking about (in English).

Anyway, for the curious, here is the actual quote in the original French:

> Je pourrais illustrer la deuxième approche, en gardant l’image de la noix qu’il s’agit d’ouvrir. La première parabole qui m’est venue à l’esprit tantôt, c’est qu’on plonge la noix dans un liquide émollient, de l’eau
> simplement pourquoi pas, de temps en temps on frotte pour qu’elle pénètre mieux, pour le reste on laisse faire
> le temps. La coque s’assouplit au fil des semaines et des mois - quand le temps est mûr, une pression de la main suffit, la coque s’ouvre comme celle d’un avocat mûr à point! Ou encore, on laisse mûrir la noix sous
> le soleil et sous la pluie et peut-être aussi sous les gelées de l’hiver. Quand le temps est mûr c’est une pousse
> délicate sortie de la substantifique chair qui aura percé la coque, comme en se jouant - ou pour mieux dire, la
> coque se sera ouverte d’elle-même, pour lui laisser passage.

and my translation:

> I could illustrate the second approach with the image of a nut that one must open. The first parable that came to my mind earlier, is immersing the nut in an emollient, perhaps water, and rubbing it occasionally, so that the water penetrates better, and we let time do its work. The shell softens over the course of weeks or months; when the time is ready, a little pressure from the hand suffices, and the nut opens up like that of a ripe avocado! Or even better, one lets the nut mature under the sun and under the rain and maybe even under the winter frosts. When the time is ripe a delicate sapling will emerge from the substantial flesh that will have pierced the shell, as if playing - or to put it better, the shell will have opened on its own, to let it pass.

So, I disagree a bit with the accepted answer: (1) there is no double entrendre in the original or in a good translation, and (2) the quote is not so much about "recasting" the problem in a more tractable form, but more about giving oneself the benefit of months or years to reflect on a problem from many different angles, rather than trying to force something through on a tight deadline.

Finally, one editorial comment: while there is certainly wisdom here, perhaps we should find a similarly elegant quote espousing the opposite view: applying energy and finishing things quickly is often better than spending years and years in deep thought without actually accomplishing anything.

Comment: This is a fine translation. Thanks for providing the real context.

Comment: Ah, good that you found the original!

Answer (score 5):

Although I do not have resources at this moment to give citations, I can aver that the phraseology about "soaking a nut" (to be able to open it) is one of Grothendieck's (and others') metaphors regarding different methodological attitudes.

Specifically, I believe it was Grothendieck who said something to the effect that Serre would deliver a sharp blow to open a hard nut... while he, Grothendieck, would gradually soak it to soften it, and almost without effort eventually open it.

The specific wording of the quote in the question, if accurate, is a cutesy middle-school-provocative rewriting of the actual comments, to achieve the ambiguity. The original (obvs in French), and the natural English translation, did not achieve such a pseudo-provocative silliness.

Comment: Regarding the French version being less crude, see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calembour

Comment: @henning, my French is insufficient to detect a double entendre in the French in this case... But a more neutral English translation seems to be "soak a nut" not "soak their nuts"... I'd have to find the original. :)